# How can I add custom font in react native without generating any error in my previous written code?

Tags: react-native, expo, custom-font

I'm using `expo-cli`, can somebody help me in using custom fonts for Expo Managed React Native projects.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt9Ni.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `expo-font`

```
expo install expo-font
```

Then install `expo-app-loading`

```
expo install expo-app-loading
```

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located.

Inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js` paste this code

`useFonts.js`

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Fontello: require('../assets/fonts/fontello.ttf'),
    // Place your custom fonts here and make sure that their location is set properly
  });
};

export default useFonts;
```

Then in your `App.js` paste this code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts(); 
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
        onError={(error) => console.log(error)}
      />
    );
  }

   return (
     <View>
         // Your App Content here
     </View
   );
}
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/font-loading)